# How to grep Rules to search for a deprecated function?

Tags: 7, rules

I'm removing an obsolete custom module, but I want to make sure it isn't referenced in any rules.

Is there a way for me to search / grep for a function name within all the rules on my site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a rule, actually a rules component, as in this (random) sample (in Rules export format):

```
{ "rules_grant_access_to_a_node" : {
    "LABEL" : "Grant access to a node",
    "PLUGIN" : "rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "USES VARIABLES" : { "node_containing_classified_ad" : { "label" : "Node containing classified ad", "type" : "node" } },
    "IF" : [
      { "node_is_of_type" : {
          "node" : [ "node-containing-classified-ad" ],
          "type" : { "value" : { "article" : "article" } }
        }
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "entity_fetch" : {
          "USING" : {
            "type" : "node",
            "id" : [ "node-containing-classified-ad:field-free-format-nr" ]
          },
          "PROVIDE" : { "entity_fetched" : { "fetched_classified_complete" : "Fetched classified complete" } }
        }
      },
      { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "Trying to grant access to node with Id = [fetched-classified-complete:field_free_format_nr]" } },
      { "content_access_action_user_grant" : [] },
      { "redirect" : { "url" : [ "fetched-classified-complete:url" ] } }
    ]
  }
}
```

The above rule (Rules Component) has a Rules Action `content_access_action_user_grant` (= machine name) which is available if (a) you have the [Content Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access) module enabled and (b) the [ACL](https://www.drupal.org/project/acl) module is enabled also. So [ACL](https://www.drupal.org/project/acl) is a [weak module dependency](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/content_access/tree/content_access_rules/content_access_rules.rules.inc?h=7.x-1.x#n113) of the [Content Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access) module.

However, that `content_access_action_user_grant` Rules Action is only available if, and for as long as, [ACL](https://www.drupal.org/project/acl) is enabled (if you disable the ACL module, then any rule that refers to that Rules Action `content_access_action_user_grant` will show a "*... fails the integrity check*").

With the above example (and Rules Action) in mind, execute an SQL query on the Drupal database which looks like so:

```
SELECT id,plugin,name,label
FROM `rules_config`
WHERE `data` LIKE '%content_access_action_user_grant%'
```

The results I get by using this query looks like so:

```
id  plugin   name                             label

216 rule     rules_grant_access_to_a_node     Grant access to a node
```

Obviously, this result with `id=216` matches with my (random) sample rule.

To execute the above query, you can use whatever SQL query tool, such as PhpMyAdmin.

Replace the machine name of the Rules Action in my example by whatever fits with your "function name" (as in your question), and a similar SQL query should list all "*rules in your site*" (as in your question) that reference your custom module.

**Note**: another approach (if you can afford to do so), is to simply disable your custom module, and then use the Rules UI to find out which Rules / Rules Components show a similar message containing such "*... fails the integrity check*".

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the detailed response. Very easy to understand. Seems so obvious, I'm just a bit ashamed that I didn't realize this myself.

Comment: @BrentConnor merci for the accept / +1 ... no need to be "ashamed" ... there seem to be plenty of users who don't realize this ***K** eep* ***I** t* ***S** uper* ***S** imple* solution to such kind of Rules-reporting (or "impact analysis"?) questions.

Answer (score -1):

The [standards documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/coding-standards/api-documentation-and-comment-standards#deprecated) recommends that modules use the [`@deprecated`](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/coding-standards/api-documentation-and-comment-standards#deprecated) tag when deprecating a function/method.

Assuming the author of any given module has followed the guidelines properly, searching for `@deprecated` should get you the correct results.